# Using dynamic inventory in Ansible python api

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-inventory

I've been using ansible dynamic inventory with ansible and ansible-playbook, is there a way to call dynamic inventory module with in ansible programmatically and run a playbook?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for how to post a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example of your code in a question.

Answer (score 0):

As Toby says, I'm not quite sure what your problem is, but the [meta](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/meta_module.html) module has a **refresh_inventory** option.